# EclipseLink "SQL string is not Query"

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm running EclipseLink on WLS 10.3.5.

I'm trying to use @NamedNativeQuery annotation, but all the SQL I try causes an "`Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: SQL string is not Query`" exception.

Even a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE` causes that error where TABLE is the table that the containing Entity is mapped to.

The annotation is:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = AnnouncementDeliveryLog.FIND_NORMALIZED_RECIPIENTS_FOR_ANNOUNCEMENT, query =  "SELECT * FROM ANNOUNCEMENT_DELIVERY_LOG", resultClass = AnnouncementDeliveryLog.class)
```

The query is being executed with:

```
em.createNativeQuery(AnnouncementDeliveryLog.FIND_NORMALIZED_RECIPIENTS_FOR_ANNOUNCEMENT).getResultList();
```

I can't find a good way to get more useful information from the system so any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong method is in use. Method [createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) takes native SQL string as an argument. In given code argument seems to be *name* of the native query. Method [createNamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNamedQuery%28java.lang.String%29) should be used, it takes name of the native query as an argument.

Comment: That's it exactly! Thank you, I couldn't see the wood for the trees there!